# create a link to another excel sheet cell with lookup for last cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, vlookup, lookup

I am using multiple sheets in excel.data will be coming from another sheet.when i click on ctrl+[ then should be go to that sheets value. which is in the last row in a column.

I can get the last value from another sheet using this formula.

=(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!G:G")))

but i want to just click and go to my values from my main sheet to another sheet which is in the last in a column which i got from using lookup function.

Comment: 1.  I cannot get what you are trying to do.  Screenshots etc. needed.   2. Is `ctrl + [` a macro shortcut or something ?

Comment: i have a main excel sheet where there is total hours column. these total come from another excel sheet.  another excel sheets contains daily work hours. i want to see another sheet when click on my main sheets total hours.,

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work.

`=HYPERLINK("#"&"'"&B2&"'!G"&MATCH((LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!G:G"))),INDIRECT(B2&"!$G:$G"),0),"Click Here to See Data")`